# Android runtime permission below android 6 marshmallow

Tags: permissions, runtime

I saw a not very popular brand Artel. Her system Android 4.2.1 well has a runtime permissions. How can I check the permissions in runtime in such devices

[image: android 4.2.1]
[image: runtime permission list]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a vendor specific implementation and not part of the official Android Runtime Permissions API. Before this was standardized, some vendors had tried to implement this in their own way.

Hence we won't be able to use any known or standard method to check if the permissions are granted in this case.